# Special characters in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping

I have a list of div, each has an id. The id also performs as a link: `"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + id` is the link to this item on wikipedia, `"/image/" + id + ".jpg"` is the local image for this item.

But I have some id with special characters. There are two types (that I found have bug): first, `A_(B)`, containing parentheses, second `A%C3%A9B` (AéB), containing special letter. I know `()` can be replaced by `%28%29`, so it is basically only one type. And I have tested, this kind of name works for image and wiki link.

The problem is, when I use jQuery, `$('#' + id)` cannot find those objects with special letters. Anyone has any idea how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) for more info.

Personally, I believe IDs should conform to human-readable, easily-understandable IDs. Consider attaching URLs using a different mechanism, like jQuery's `$.data`, or another property that doesn't have validity restrictions.

Comment: I believe so. It will be much easier. I use title to record that link name instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the second paragraph of the [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) page, it shows you that these characters ``` !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^``{|}~ ``` need to be escaped when used.

But if you are including other characters it might be best to use their escape code to include them ( [google closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) will automatically do this for you ). So this letter `é` can be replaced with `\u00e9`

Answer (score 1):

have you tried:

```
var id = encodeURIComponent(id);
$('#' + id);
```

to see if it resolves it?

Answer (score 0):

A good rule of thumb is to first conform to relevant specifications. According to [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

So characters like (, ) and % are not allowed in element ids or names.

Non-conforming characters in ids are likely to cause issues other than with jQuery. Using *encodeURIComponent* (e.g. to replace ( with %28) doesn't help because the % character isn't allowed either. But you can get away with character entities for letters outside the typical a-z,A-Z range, or you could just use plain old *document.getElementById* and if you really need to use jQuery:

```
$(document.getElementById(id))
```

may be sufficient (but not reliable).